# Linux chcon: can't apply partial context to unlabeled file

Tags: linux, centos, selinux

I'm getting and error when i'm trying to run this command:

```
chcon -t textrel_shlib_t /usr/lib/vmware-vcli/bin/esxcli/_ssl.so
```

The error that i got:

```
chcon: can't apply partial context to unlabeled file `/usr/lib/vmware-vcli/bin/esxcli/_ssl.so'
```

Any idea how to solve it?

Comment: maybe you will find help here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23610/chcon-cant-apply-partial-context-to-unlabeled-file-while-installing-nagios-wit

Answer (score 5):

Try to run this:

```
chcon -h system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t  /usr/lib/vmware-vcli/bin/esxcli/_ssl.so
```

instead of:

```
chcon -t textrel_shlib_t /usr/lib/vmware-vcli/bin/esxcli/_ssl.so
```

Answer (score 3):

There's not quite enough context of what your goal is to answer with great accuracy, but here's some things that may help.

If you want to restore a context to a section of a directory tree:
restorecon -rnv /path/to/dir

the flags are recursive, no-changes, and verbose

You can also use use 
chcon --reference=file_with_good_perms your_file

ls -Z --> to view selinux contexts